# Angular chained typeaheads break with whitespace

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead

Given two entries with typeaheads, one chained to the other (selection in the first determines choicelist for the second), there seems to be an issue with values containing whitespace, even though the entries are linked by id, not display value.

The behaviour is best shown in a demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49dvyae6/)

To reproduce:

1. select an object in the first typeahead
2. select an object in the second typeahead, see that it works
3. select the object named *broken* in the first typeahead
4. try to select an object in the second typeahead, there is **no choicelist available**

The `id` of the object selected in the first entry determines the choicelist of the second. However, if there is a space at the **end** of the `name` of the selected object, the second typeahead breaks.

If you were to remove the space at the end of `Broken` , the second entry starts working as expected.

This seems like a bug to me, since the display value of the first entry should play no part in the second.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add ng-trim="false" in the first input. It solves the issue. It happens as Angular removes the end space on blur.

```
    <input type="text"
           id="estate"
           cam-variable-type="String"
           ng-model="line.estate"
           uib-typeahead="estate as (estate.id + ' - ' + estate.name) for estate in estates | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10"
           typeahead-min-length="1"
           typeahead-no-results="noResults"
           typeahead-select-on-blur="true"
           autocomplete="off"
           ng-trim="false"
           class="form-control form-input">
```

Comment: This neither solves the issue nor explains why the display name is involved in linking the entries when the list is selected by the id

Comment: When you add something in first input and go out of the input .. angular trims the last space.. so actually id becomes null in `line.estate.id`. So when you off that ng-trim from first input it starts working.

Comment: You are right, it *does* solve the issue, sorry, I misread it the first time.

Comment: OTOH, it does not explain **why** the display name is of any concern for the second input. If I console.log out the line.estate in typeahead-on-select, you can see that the whole data object is selected. And it's the ID that is releveant for the second input. Does angular somehow identify objects by name?
https://jsfiddle.net/dph06ewm/